# heroku: issue importing python module

Tags: python, heroku, python-import

This is my project structure:

```
project_name
|___src
    |___model.py
```

On my local dev environment, I have added `project_name`'s parent directory to PYTHONPATH, so I can do `from project_name.src.model import func_name` in a file inside the project.

But when I push the project to heroku, it pushes the contents of `project_name` inside an `app` directory, hence my imports fail.

Is there any way to make this work on heroku?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. The issue in my case was the module name in my case was clashing with a internal module of heroku/gunicorn.

A possible fix is to have this folder structure.

```
project_name
|___internal_package_name
    |___src
        |___model.py
        |...others
    |___domain
    |___others
|___wsgi.py
```

Answer (score -2):

Do that path manipulation inside wsgi.py instead.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Also, I don't have a wsgi.py.

Comment: Elaborate how? And you do definitely have a wsgi file, otherwise your application couldn't run.